# SELECT to Skip First and Last Rows and Select in Between

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to to skip the first and last rows in my SQL query (i.e. skip where `sequence=0` and `sequence=4` in this case) but my SQL query does not seem to be working. Any idea why? The logic seems correct:

```
SELECT * FROM waypoint 
WHERE id NOT IN(
        (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM waypoint), 
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM waypoint)
      )
AND booking_id="1";
```

[**MY SQL FIDDLE IS HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82f84/8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 7 rows. Their id's are from 1 to 7. Your `not in` clause filters out 1 and 7. If you want to skip first and last with `booking_id=1` you should add this clause to subselects:

```
SELECT * FROM waypoint 
WHERE id NOT IN(
        (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM waypoint where booking_id="1"), 
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM waypoint where booking_id="1")
      )
AND booking_id="1";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy your second part of your `where` clause into the select of your  `not in` clause, because each `select` is handled for its own and has access to the whole dataset. So you need to add the restriction logic to each `select`. Otherwise your `MAX(ID)` will return 7 because it has access to the whole dataset:

```
SELECT * FROM waypoint 
WHERE id NOT IN(
        (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM waypoint where booking_id="1"), 
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM waypoint where booking_id="1")
      )
AND booking_id="1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it works and I cannot test it here in the moment but have you tried

```
SELECT * FROM waypoint WHERE booking_id="1" ORDER BY ID LIMIT 2,COUNT(ID)
```

This could be more perfoment because you dont need two subselects.

Comment: Nice idea, but you cannot do that